# Why I can't use dispatch a thunk inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Inside `thunks.js`

```
export const displayAlert = (text) => () => {   alert(`${text}`); }
```

Inside another file

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const example = () => {    
    useEffect(
        ()=>{dispatch(displayAlert('Hello'))}
        ) }
```

Shows me

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call

Comment: hooks can only be used inside a functional component or inside another hook, i.e. a custom hook. You probably meant to call `useDispatch` inside the `example()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `useDispatch` hook into the component, and rename it with capital letter (to not trigger another lint warning):

```
const Example = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(displayAlert("Hello"));
  });
};
```

See [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).